# Decidability of determining the definition of a function

Tags: logic, computability

Let's say a **property** is an SMT formula.

Let's say a function ***has a property*** iff, with addition of the function symbol to a ***monadic predicate calculus*** formula over the signature of ***Presburger arithmetic***, that formula is satisfiable. For example, we say that the function $f$ has the property $\forall x, f(x) = x$

Given an arbitrary function symbol $\Phi$, an arbitrary domain $D$, an arbitrary range $R$ such that $$\Phi: D \mapsto R$$ and given a set of properties that the function $\Phi$ has, then is it decidable in the general case to find a definition of the function $\Phi$. In other words, is it decidable to find, in this general case, one property which implies all the others? For example, if you define $f(x) = 2+x$ then the relation $(x, 2+x)$ is a property which would entail all the other properties that $f$ has.

For another example, look back to the above example with function $f$ where $f$ has the property $\forall x, f(x) = x$. This suggests an obvious definition for $f$, but some cases might not be so trivial and I am concerned that this problem is undecidable in its most general setting, but I am not able to prove it to myself.

Comment: What language do you use to write the definition of your function? If for you a definition must be a finite sequence of symbols in a countable alphabet, then obviously, by a simple cardinality argument, most functions are not definable

Comment: When you write "SMT", I suspect you have "satisfiability modulo theories" in mind. In terms that are more likely to be understood on this forum, I think you mean"first-order formula over some signature". Is that right?

Comment: @RobArthan I've added that in.

Comment: @Tryss, the function should be definable by assumption. In other words, start with a definable function $f$, obtain its set of properties, and then forget about $f$; is there an algorithm that recovers $f$ from the set of properties?

Comment: What would a counterexample to this look like? A function that cannot be recovered given any set of properties? Is $\forall x . x = 0.1 \implies f(x) = 0.2$ a property? If so given a function couldn't you make a set of properties like: $\{ \forall x . x = n \implies f(x) = f(n) | n \in D \}$

Comment: @blacklemon67 Yes that first formula is a property. But that is not a valid counter-example. If it is decidable to determine the definition of a function then it is decidable to find a property that entails all the other properties of the function. For a counter-example, you would need to construct a proper class of properties and show that it is undecidable to find a single property that entails all the elements of that proper class.